# How to transpose a matrix of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix, constants

I have a matrix of a layout

```
const int boatRect[MAX_BITMAP_SIZE][MAX_BITMAP_SIZE] = { // 5
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}
};
```

and a struct with a pointer to it (matrix):

```
typedef struct bitmap {
    Shape shape;
    const int (*matrix)[MAX_BITMAP_SIZE];
    int orientation;
    int size;
} Bitmap;
```

I then want to transpose(part of the rotation process) the matrix in the struct:

```
void transpose(const int (*shape)[MAX_BITMAP_SIZE]) {
    const int *temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_BITMAP_SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            temp = (const int *) shape[i][j]; //Cast to 'const int *' from smaller integer type 'int'
            shape[i][j] = shape[j][i];        //Read-only variable is not assignable
            shape[j][i] = temp;               //Read-only variable is not assignable
        }
    }
}
```

but I get those errors, I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong!

I'm trying to do it this way to only have one matrix in the code and have pointers to it and rotate those pointers in a way that they convey the rotated matrix without creating another one.

So how do I in my Bitmap struct create a matrix of pointers that point to the const int matrix, and then rotate that matrix of pointers(not the one of int)?

Comment: You need to change the function signature to `void transpose(int (*shape)[MAX_BITMAP_SIZE])` The warning about the cast will persist, but you can get rid of that by changing `const int *temp;` to `const int temp;` and removing the cast (since you're assigning an int to an int).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix isn't a "matrix of pointers", which would be a matrix whose elements are pointers. It's a matrix of integers. You define it as an array of arrays of `int`.

```
const int boatRect[MAX_BITMAP_SIZE][MAX_BITMAP_SIZE] = { ... };
```

Like other arrays, it can be represented as a pointer to its first element, which in your case is an array of `MAX_BITMAP_SIZE` ints.

```
const int (*matrix)[MAX_BITMAP_SIZE];
```

Dereferencing it twice will give you an `int`, namely the integer value at the given row and column. Therefore, your `temp` variable for swapping should be an `int`:

```
int temp = shape[i][j];
```

No casting necessary! (The warning means that `int`s are "narrower" than a pointer on your system and that you will lose information in the assignment.)

With that change, the second error will still persist: You have made the matrix `const`: The elements of a `const T*` cannot be changed. If you want to modify the matrix in place, don't make it `const`. (You can still make it locally `const` in functions that access, but don't modify it.)

Comment: I know the original matrix is not a matrix of pointers, but i want to have a pointer matrix that points to it, and then rotate that pointer matrix

Comment: So you want to have a matrix whose elements are pointers to the integer elements of the original matrix? And if you inverse matrix you just swap pointers? In my opinion, that doesn't make sense. What you have is a pointer to a matrix, so that your structure just keeps a pointer without copying the whole matrix. If you modify the matrix through that pointer, you change the original matrix, because they are the same.

Comment: then what would be the best way of only having a single matrix in memory? because that's my goal, or else I wouldn't be messing with pointers, I would just copy it over

Comment: That's what you have done, except that you seem to have a misconception about what part the pointer is: The pointer is the outer part; it doesn't affect the inner parts. Take a simple array: `int a = [1, 2, 3]`. Now define a pointer to it: `int *p = a`. Both `a[0]` and `p[0]` access the first element of `a` and assigning a new value to `p[0]` will also change element `a[0]` of the underlying array. That's what you want, right? (cont'd)

Comment: Observe that here, the elements of both `a` and `p` are `int`s. `p` itself is a pointer, but what it points to is integers. Now you use that method for a two-dimensional array, `int M[5][5]`. The elements of `M` are arrays of five ints. A pointer to that array is an `int (*P)[5]`. (That syntax needs some getting used to at first.) `P` points to an array of five ints and both `M[0]` and `P[0]` access the first row of your matrix. In order to get at the integer in a certain column of that row, you must provide the second index: `M[0][i]` and `P[0][j]` are the same integer.

Comment: I just want to change to where the pointer points, I don't actually want to change the values!
If I had a 2*2 matrix with `{ {0,1}, {0,1} }` I want each struct to have a matrix of pointers `{ {ptr1, ptr2}, {ptr3, ptr4} }` and in my rotate function I want get that pointer matrix rotated `{ {ptr2, ptr4}, {ptr1, ptr3} }` but keep the original matrix as `{ {0,1}, {0,1} }`! can I do this or is it completely stupid? I'm just trying to have the least assets in memory as possible :/

Comment: Perhaps a `typedef` may be useful here: `typedef int Matrix5x5[5][5];` Define a matrix with `Matrix5x5 m = {{...}};`. Now your struct member, the pointer to that matrix, is `Matrix5x5 *p;`, just as with every other type. (But creating typedefs for arrays of fixed sizes obscures the nature of the type, so I usually don't do it.)

Comment: But that way I would have a pointer to a matrix, I want a matrix of pointers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212196/discussion-between-obvionaoe-and-m-oehm).

Comment: Okay, we were talking at cross pruposes here. You actually _did_ want to have a matrix of pointers. That's not stupid, but I don't see the real benefit here. Your base data type, integers, are small, usually smaller than a pointer. Creating a new matrix is just as cheap, memory-wise, as creating a matrix of pointers. Having an array of pointers is still a useful technique: Imagine you have a one-dimensional array of big objects, each of them a kilobyte. You want to display them in o specific order. Instead of sorting them, create an array of light-weight pointers, and sort that indirectly.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to have a matrix of pointers, define `int *pm[5][5]`. You can no longer assign the matrix with a single instruction, you have to initialize each element with `pm[j][i] = &m[j][i]` explicitly.